# PNG background images in Firefox 3.x disappear and do not load

Tags: css, firefox, png, background

The problem is this:

I have a div (#bottom), which is NOT floated, which has a pre-defined height in CSS (of 24px;), which USED TO display its background (bottom.png) until I put something inside.

```
CSS:

#bottom {height: 24px; background-image: url("bottom.png");}

HTML: 

<div id="bottom">
<div id="somethingInside">
</div>
</div>
```

Now FF 3.x does not LOAD the background image! I can put another image used on the same page, within the same html file, and make CSS use it as a background image for that #bottom div and then it shows up there.

But I can't load the image in the browser EVEN if I click "show background image" in FF context menu or when I enter the bottom.png path. Instead only the path to the bottom.png file shows there... If I use a gif file than everything works fine. When I use a PNG, then it doesn't work.

If I rename the bottom.png to whatever.png, it does not load either. If I invoke bottom.png as a background anywhere else in the same file, it doesn't work.

If I remove the div#somethinginside from div#bottom, the problem persists.

It all changed after I included bottom.png into div#bottom as `<img src="bottom.png" />`, then the background returned, the  was displayed but some other pngs I used below in the file disappeared.

This is by far the most annoying phenomena I have ever encountered, as I can't find any explanation for that. It looks as if Firefox blacklisted that file or something, stupid it may sound, though.

It's not a path issue: i have many files in the same folder.
It's not a '/" in url("myUrl") in CSS issue: I copy/paste paths for files that do work.
I always save via Save for web in Photoshop. The same happens, irrespective of whether I'm using PNG 8 and PNG 24 images. 
I'm working on a local server, XAMPP. 
I'm using Joomla. And Windows XP Pro. And it ONLY happens in Firefox, currently 3.5.7 for me. Not an issue in IE8.

Has anyone encountered a problem like that? I can't even reproduce it on demand since i don't even know what's causing this strange behavior. And it applies mostly to PNG files for some reason. It's the second time this happens, and it's a completely different project. Is there some PNG/Firefox bug?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the quotes so it looks like this: `background-image: url(bottom.png)`?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this does not help. What is more, after I added a background-color: #FFF; property, the botoom.png disappeared again. That _is_ weird...

Comment: And it's not an issue on the productive server...

Comment: I have this same issue. FF 3.x will not load background images that are .png. I do not know why but it's pissing me off. If I change the image to another format then it will work. The annoying part is that firefox WILL load a .png image in an image tag, just not as a CSS background rule.

Comment: It might have something to do with either disk errors or XAMPP mis-doing something. I have never encountered that kind of behavior while working on productive servers or working on linux...

Comment: I am actually having the same issue - started a new project where all of the assets are png's and the background image does not display even though the path is correct and confirmed by Firebug. Firebug reports "failed to load the given URL"

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox it´s easy, just use firebug to see what´s happening.

By the way, have you tried it in Firefox in Safe Mode? Perhaps it´s an add-on that´s causing trouble.

And with what browsers (and versions) does it work?

Comment: Well, the problem is that Firebug does not load the image either. But the file is physically there in that path, I can view it anytime from that location...

I'll check out the safe mode.

It works under newest Opera (January 2010) and IE6,7 and 8.